# Creating a Bot Channel Registration using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am in a process to create **Bot Channels Registration** using Power-Shell. I got a reference of PowerShell script from Azure, but in that we have two JSON files called paramerters.json and template.json. When I ran the script, it was asking me some details and after providing the parameter details, getting below

```
**error**: New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:46:22 PM - Resource Microsoft.BotService/botServices 'samplefromps' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidBotData",
    "message": "MsaAppId: Microsoft App ID is not a valid GUID. "
  }
}'
```

I have provided all the parameters required for deployment. But not sure where I am missing. Please do the helpful on this issue, Thank You - GSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems in your template, App id is not valid. The app id should be like `e59499b8-b279-48c4-9eb8-b6161a705ae1`. The id is unique.

[image]

More information about guid you could check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: You could use PowerShell to generate a guid.`[guid]::NewGuid()`. More information about this you could check this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/25/powertip-create-a-new-guid-by-using-powershell/)

Comment: thank you. Yeah it's a GUID issue and working fine now.